# Побитовое И в C#

Tags: c#, битовые-операции

Мне нужно перевести подобную строку кода -

```
if (a & b) 
{

}
```

Где `a` - int, `b` - число из enum.

В C++ имеется оператор "побитовое И". Можно ли подобное сделать на С#?

Comment: _"Можно ли подобное сделать на С#?"_ -- да. см. [Побитовые операторы C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/17zwb64t(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Запросто.
В C#, как и в C++, за побитовое И отвечает оператор `&`.
Ваш пример будет выглядеть следующим образом.

Если `a` и `b` имеют одинаковый значащий тип (например `int`, или какой-то `enum`):

```
if ((a & b) != 0) {

}
```

Если `b` имеет типом какой-либо `enum`:

```
if ((a & (int)b) != 0) {

}
```